# Wrap different style to specific text between <li></li> before textual colon ":"?

Tags: jquery, css

Before I lose myself in words trying to explain what I mean, here's an example of what I'd like to achieve.

**How it is now:**

```
<ul>
    <li>My name: Sietse</li>
    <li>Country: The Netherlands</li>
</ul>
```

**How I'd like it to be:**

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>My name:</strong> Sietse</li>
    <li><strong>Country:</strong> The Netherlands</li>
</ul>
```

There is a lot of existing content on my website that is marked up like the first example, but is there a way to dynamically select and style the text until the (possibly including) the colon in the LI, as displayed in the second example?

Please note that I'm an absolute beginner in jQuery or any Javascript for that matter.

Comment: You cannot style a piece of text without making it an element. This can be done dynamically with JavaScript, but as this is more of a structural feature, why don’t you simply change the markup to be what you’d like it to be? Or maybe to a table, since this looks more like tabular data than just a list.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ckoa23y9/

Comment: Spend half an hour or so, with Find and Replace in Files, and fix it. Rather than dynamically patching it for EVERY request.

Comment: well, if I were to go that way I'd spend the entire day fixing this :) there's a lot of content. But on that note: would Arun P Johny's solution create too much strain on my server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and string [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like

```js
$('ul li').html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(.*?:)/, '<strong>$1</strong>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>My name: Sietse</li>
    <li>Country: The Netherlands</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul li").each(function() {
   if ($(this).text().indexOf(':') > -1) {
       $(this).html('<strong>' + $(this).html().split(':').join(':</strong>')); 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>My name: Sietse</li>
  <li>Country: The Netherlands</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for another quick answer. However, although it looks like the solution Arun P Johny presented, it doesn't seem to work out of the box. I think it targets too many LI's, instead of just the ones in the the content text.