# How to style HTML text between quotes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to automatically style all words on a page that are enclosed in quotes, but can't seem to figure it out with my **very** basic jQuery skills. Here's an example:

**How it is now:**

```
<p>"Hi, I'm Sietse", he said.</p>
```

**How I'd like it to be:**

```
<p><strong>"Hi, I'm Sietse"</strong>, he said.</p>
```

Any clues?

I recently asked a similar question here: [Wrap different style to specific text between <li></li> before textual colon ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480530/wrap-different-style-to-specific-text-between-li-li-before-textual-colon), but I can't seem to use these methods for this new problem. (for some reason this question is still marked as duplicate, which it isn't)

Comment: just change the regex - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vqz4e7zs/1/

Comment: Thanks for another quick answer Arun, this works like a charm! (if you can post it as an answer I can vote for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to do it

```js
$('p').html(function(i,v){
    return v.replace(/(".*")/g,'<strong>$1</strong>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>"Hi, I'm Sietse", he said.</p>
```

**Update**

As you commented below , for complex text with multiple `""` use the following

```js
$('p').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/("[^"]*")/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>"Hi, I'm Sietse", he said, "and I'm from the Netherlands"</p>
```

Comment: Although the solution is exactly what I requested, I now run into an additional problem: When I use this script it also affects the text between two sets of quotes, for example:

"Hi, I'm Sietse", he said, "and I'm from the Netherlands", he continued.

In this case the script wraps ", he said," in <strong> tags as well. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Sietse : ok i will check and reply :)

Comment: @Sietse : use the following in that case `a.replace(/("[^"]*")/g,'<strong>$1</strong>')`

Comment: Hmm, can't seem to get that to work, could you make that in an example?

Comment: @Sietse http://jsfiddle.net/gj4a47r5/

Comment: You rock! is it possible for you to write that solution as another answer so I can vote for it?

Comment: @Sietse : no need for that... glad to help you :)